# Running Puppeteer with headless: false & Firebase Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I'm trying to use Puppeteer + Firebase Functions while using the headless: false option

```
await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
```

It works well locally. I use the headless: false so it won't trigger a bot check, which work well.

When I deploy it to Firebase Functions it doesn't seem to be able to launch a browser:

`Error: Failed to launch the browser process!`

`[15:32:0209/162803.759118:ERROR:file_path_watcher_linux.cc(78)] Failed to read /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

`[15:15:0209/162804.834741:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(234)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY`

`[15:15:0209/162804.834794:ERROR:env.cc(225)] The platform failed to initialize. Exiting.`

Is there some sort of a solution to run it as a Firebase Function?

Comment: Hi! Can you please share feedback on my answer to know if further assistance is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I’ll start with the cases that combined Cloud functions and Puppeteer. Here is an old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930743/puppeteer-not-working-with-google-cloud-functions-in-node-10-runtime) that discusses the same log error. I think this is the first place to look for a solution, as it provides links to a couple of Github Issues reporting similar error logs. In this other [Github issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5450#issuecomment-855235985), a user recommended code to start Puppeteer in Cloud functions. [This example](https://jmolivas.com/how-run-puppeteer-headless-chrome-using-google-firebase-cloud-functions) can help you as well.

I’ll leave these two guides that can walk you through. This old [medium article](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-puppeteer-microservice-deploy-google-cloud-functions/) and this more updated version from [logrocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-puppeteer-microservice-deploy-google-cloud-functions/).

[Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942859/puppeteer-not-running-in-headlessfalse-mode) has several workarounds; unfortunately, none of them include Cloud Functions, just in case this is caused purely by Puppeteer. And here is [how to run Headful Mode](https://nitayneeman.com/posts/getting-to-know-puppeteer-using-practical-examples/#headful-mode).

However, if you want to avoid being detected by the bot, there is also a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364643/headless-browser-detection) about this that could give you some hints.

There is no exact solution for this, as it seems there are several causes and workarounds. I would advise you to open a new question once you have tried some alternatives already provided by the community, and see if there's a more specific solution.

Comment: It didn't help, I'm aiming for Firebase Functions and Headful

Comment: It would be much appreciated if you could share what you have tried so far and if those workarounds have given you any logs or information useful to find a solution. The first link involves a very similar case with Cloud Functions and headless (Puppeteer). Both versions of Cloud Functions are very similar. See [What is the difference between Cloud Functions and Firebase Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854865)